# Allow user to insert a custom image

Tags: vb.net

I was in the middle of making a VB.NET (Visual Basic 2010 Express) application when I hatched an idea. I want users to be able to insert their own images into my application. How would I do so? I know it has something to do with the open file dialog.

Comment: Please be specific in your queries..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the following code.
if you want to show it in a picturebox, you can follow the below code, else you can save the byte data of the image into DB.

```
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
```

Comment: That's a start, but you'll want some error handling in there before you try to assign PictureBox1.Image to just any old file.  Maybe limit the File Dialog to certain file extensions.

Comment: apparently 'OpenFileDialog1' does not exist... where does this code go?